# convert text to title jinja template

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Just converting from Django template to jinja2 files i'll like to know how to convert a text to title  format from lower or upper case letter.Ill like to do something like this.

```
{{sometext |title }}
```

thanks

Comment: There is a filter called [title](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#title)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out it works just like the Django template as-well

```
{{some_object.some_variable_thats_a_string_or_unicode|title }}
```